# Changing baseline to top for pspicture

Tags: errors, pstricks

I tried to align text with the top of a figure. The `pstricks` manual says that I can specify an option to the `pspicture` environment, but this somehow does not work. I get an error message.

``` ! Package xkeyval Error: ``1' undefined in families ``,pstricks,pst-node'. ```

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks,pst-node}

\begin{document}

Test {\begin{pspicture}(2.6,0)(7.4,4.3)
%\psgrid
\rput[B](3,0){\rnode{Peter}{Peter}}
\rput[B](6,0){\rnode{schlaeft}{sleeps}}
%
\rput[B](6,2){\rnode{v}{V[\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
                          subj ,\\
                          comps ]
                          \end{tabular}}}
\rput[B](3,2){\rnode{np1}{1 NP[{nom}]}}
%
\rput[B](4.5,4){\rnode{vp}{V[\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
                             subj \\
                          comps  ]
                          \end{tabular}}}
%
\psset{angleA=-90,angleB=90,arm=0pt}
%
\ncdiag{v}{schlaeft}
\ncdiag{np1}{Peter}
\ncdiag{vp}{np1}\ncdiag{vp}{v}
%
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If I remove the open brace before `\begin{pspicture}`, I get no error.

Comment: I used `\begin{pspicture}[1](2.6,0)...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `shift` option:

```
[...]
Test \begin{pspicture}[shift=-4](2.6,0)(7.4,4.3)
\rput[B](3,0){\rnode{Peter}{Peter}}
[...]
```

-4 is the y coordinate of your first text

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if converting the `pspicture` environment to macro structure will have any adverse effects, but the `\belowbaseline` command of `stackengine` will do the trick external to `pspicture`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks,pst-node}
\usepackage{stackengine}

\begin{document}

Test 
\belowbaseline[-\ht\strutbox]
{\pspicture(2.6,0)(7.4,4.3)
%\psgrid
\rput[B](3,0){\rnode{Peter}{Peter}}
\rput[B](6,0){\rnode{schlaeft}{sleeps}}
%
\rput[B](6,2){\rnode{v}{V[\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
                          subj ,\\
                          comps ]
                          \end{tabular}}}
\rput[B](3,2){\rnode{np1}{1 NP[{nom}]}}
%
\rput[B](4.5,4){\rnode{vp}{V[\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
                             subj \\
                          comps  ]
                          \end{tabular}}}
%
\psset{angleA=-90,angleB=90,arm=0pt}
%
\ncdiag{v}{schlaeft}
\ncdiag{np1}{Peter}
\ncdiag{vp}{np1}\ncdiag{vp}{v}
%
\endpspicture
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can give an asterisk to the `shift` option:

```
Test \begin{pspicture}[shift=*](2.6,0)(7.4,4.3)
\rput[B](3,0){\rnode{Peter}{Peter}}
```